# How to keep my image caption grid floating correctly with different sized text content

Tags: css, css-float

I have an issue here where if a caption is too long, if it extends beyond one line it causes the elements following to not float correctly. I would like to have it, so that no matter on the content of the caption, the following row adjusts to the space. I have seen [another](http://www.stockholmdesignlab.se/) site achieve something very similar.

I can't work out what else I need.

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:after, .group:before, .group:after, .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .row:before, .row:after {
 content: '\0020';
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}
.container:after, .row:after, .clearfix:after, .group:after {
 clear: both;
}
.row, .clearfix, .group {
 zoom: 1;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 color: #000;
 background: #FFF
}
.column {
 float: left;
 display: block
}
.constraint {
 padding-right: 2%;
 padding-left: 2%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 width: 100%
}
.col-4 {
 width: 33.33333333%
}
.columns {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px 
}
.row {
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: auto
}
.picture {
 height: 0;
 position: relative;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat 
}
.thumb,
.thumb-title,
.thumb-description {
  margin-bottom: 1rem
}
.picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 65% 
}
section#projects .picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 75%;
 background-position: inherit 
}
.project-thumbnail {
 margin-bottom: 80px;
 margin-bottom: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
  <div class="constraint">
    <section id="projects"> 
      <!-- Row -->
      <div class="row"> 
        <!-- Project previews -->
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview with some content that makes it extend onto another line.</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

CSS Tricks say:

> The Overflow Method relies on setting the overflow CSS property on a parent element. If this property is set to auto or hidden on the parent element, the parent will expand to contain the floats

Reading this, I set the container `div.project-thumbnail`, but no change:

```
.project-thumbnail {
  overflow: auto
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dma0bq3q/2/)

---

EDIT

As the comment suggests, setting a height to the caption div `div.thumb` would enable it to float correctly. A fixed height will cut off content that becomes too big for it. Adding `overflow: auto` to this div will just add a scrollbar to it, this is not what I am after.

---

EDIT

This site [here](http://www.stockholmdesignlab.se/) has a similar system. Items with a width are floated, no row separator, but if the content within their div extends beyond a few lines, the bottom of the div will adjust, aligning the next row neatly.

Comment: You could try inline-blocks instead of floats. It's common for unequal-height floats to snag like that.

Comment: @FilmFiddler Internet Exploder doesn't get on with inline-block does it?

Comment: You can use flexbox https://codepen.io/dakata911/pen/POgrVL

Comment: In order to get a proper response you need to provide a [mcve] featuring the problem. The code you're currently showing does not replicate your problem. Most probably, you are loading additional CSS from external libraries which applies to your elements. We can't help you fix the issue if we don't know what CSS rules currently apply to your markup. Use the `<>` button to create a live snippet and make sure you add all required resources from CDN sources and/or using the appropriate code panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First solution

This is what you are looking for,  you have to add just one rule to your css,

```
.row article:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear: left;
}
```

```css
.row article:nth-child(3n+1){
 clear: left;
}
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:after, .group:before, .group:after, .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .row:before, .row:after {
 content: '\0020';
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}
.container:after, .row:after, .clearfix:after, .group:after {
 clear: both;
}
.row, .clearfix, .group {
 zoom: 1;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 color: #000;
 background: #FFF
}
.column {
 float: left;
 display: block
}
.constraint {
 padding-right: 2%;
 padding-left: 2%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 width: 100%
}
.col-4 {
 width: 33.33333333%
}
.columns {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px 
}
.row {
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: auto
}
.picture {
 height: 0;
 position: relative;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat 
}
.thumb,
.thumb-title,
.thumb-description {
  margin-bottom: 1rem
}
.picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 65% 
}
section#projects .picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 75%;
 background-position: inherit 
}
.project-thumbnail {
 margin-bottom: 80px;
 margin-bottom: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="constraint">
    <section id="projects"> 
      <!-- Row -->
      <div class="row"> 
        <!-- Project previews -->
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview with some content that makes it extend onto another line.</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

### Second solution : inline block display

Fluid, scalable easy to grasp

I prefer this solution, using `display:inline-block` which is straightforward and works fine now for IE. The only downfall is the white spaces between the markup(which I've chosen to delete them here).

I've just taken liberty to modify your code so you can find what just the modifications.

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:after, .group:before, .group:after, .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .row:before, .row:after {
 content: '\0020';
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}
.container:after, .row:after, .clearfix:after, .group:after {
 clear: both;
}
.row, .clearfix, .group {
 zoom: 1;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 color: #000;
 background: #FFF
}
.column {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.constraint {
 padding-right: 2%;
 padding-left: 2%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 width: 100%
}
.col-4 {
 width: 33.33333333%
}
.columns {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px 
}
.row {
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: auto
}
.picture {
 height: 0;
 position: relative;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat 
}
.thumb,
.thumb-title,
.thumb-description {
  margin-bottom: 1rem
}
.picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 65% 
}
section#projects .picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 75%;
 background-position: inherit 
}
.project-thumbnail {
 margin-bottom: 80px;
 margin-bottom: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="constraint">
    <section id="projects"> 
      <!-- Row -->
      <div class="row"> 
        <!-- Project previews -->
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article><article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview with some content that makes it extend onto another line.</p>
             </div>
        </article><article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article><article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article><article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article><article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

### Third solution: grid layout

Very cool powerful modern CSS feature, you can get some more [info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}



body, html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 color: #000;
 background: #FFF
}

.constraint {
 /*! padding-right: 2%; */
 /*! padding-left: 2%; */
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 width: 100%;
}
.col-4 {
 /*! width: 33.33333333% */
}
.columns {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px; 
}
.row {
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: auto;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.picture {
 height: 0;
 position: relative;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat 
}
.thumb,
.thumb-title,
.thumb-description {
  margin-bottom: 1rem
}
.picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 65% 
}
section#projects .picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 75%;
 background-position: inherit 
}
.project-thumbnail {
 margin-bottom: 80px;
 margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="constraint">
    <section id="projects"> 
      <!-- Row -->
      <div class="row"> 
        <!-- Project previews -->
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview with some content that makes it extend onto another line.</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: The Grid solution is by far the more elegant. Definitely the way to go if OP can. Great article here about when to start and fallbacks --> https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/07/04/is-it-really-safe-to-start-using-css-grid-layout/

Answer (score 3):

**updated**, thanks to @user10089632 for comment

To get the layout you want using `float`, try adding the `clear` property to every 4th `.column`.

*example*

```
.column:nth-child(3n + 4) {
  clear: both;
}
```

This will target every 3rd `.column`, beginning from the 4th `.column` (you don't need to apply the rule to the first div in your example)

You can adjust `nth-child(n)` if you need to change your grid to 4 x 4 or something else.

You can apply this code to `article` instead, depending on the rest of your site.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/uh37qef4/2/)

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:after, .group:before, .group:after, .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after, .row:before, .row:after {
 content: '\0020';
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
}
.container:after, .row:after, .clearfix:after, .group:after {
 clear: both;
}
.row, .clearfix, .group {
 zoom: 1;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 color: #000;
 background: #FFF
}
.column {
 float: left;
 display: block
}
.constraint {
 padding-right: 2%;
 padding-left: 2%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 width: 100%
}
.col-4 {
 width: 33.33333333%
}
.columns {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px 
}
.row {
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: auto
}
.picture {
 height: 0;
 position: relative;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat 
}
.thumb,
.thumb-title,
.thumb-description {
  margin-bottom: 1rem
}
.picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 65% 
}
section#projects .picture.portrait {
 padding-bottom: 75%;
 background-position: inherit 
}
.project-thumbnail {
 margin-bottom: 80px;
 margin-bottom: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden
}

.column:nth-child(4) {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
  <div class="constraint">
    <section id="projects"> 
      <!-- Row -->
      <div class="row"> 
        <!-- Project previews -->
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview with some content that makes it extend onto another line.</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        <article class="project-thumbnail col-4 columns column">
            <div class="picture portrait" style="background-image:url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg'); background-position: 50%"> </div>
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Comment: @davvv, this solution is not scallable, say you have 12 elements instead of just 6 and you will have to add this for every forth element, please see the fix in my answer.

Comment: @user10089632 How do you mean?

Comment: @sol, [please look here](https://jsfiddle.net/nasdao/8x6mdqt0/) I've copied your code but added more thumbnails, scroll and see.

Comment: @user10089632 Oh yes, thanks for pointing that out. Corrected now!

Comment: @user10089632 is it better to use `clear:left` or `both`?

Comment: @davvv, here basically the same because you have only `float:left` but if you have some elements floating right and other left, you should use `clear:both` to make the element drop below them

Comment: @davvv, I advise you try new modern layout that are more practical, as in my answer. please note that I've added the grid script of your case, and grids can be way useful ans easily implemented in many many situations.

Comment: I like the modern grid layout. There is something beautiful about float though. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This all seems like a bit too much code.

I have simplified it using Flexbox (as shown below).

Here is what I did:

**For .center**
I added a class called "center" to the div that contains the container of the grid. It basically centers your section.

**For section**
The section is the container of all the grid elements. I added display, flex-direction, flex-wrap and width. You do not necessary need to declare all of them (except for display) since some of them are defaults that come with using display:flex. I encourage you to test it all out in your console.

**For article**
You need to declare the width and margin here. I am declaring 4 columns. 
Here is an example of how to calculate with 2 columns:

Since my margin is at 1.66%, my total margin space is 6.64% 
How did I come up with that number? The first grid element has a margin to the right and to the left. The second grid element has a margin to the right and to the left. So, 1.66% X 4

I then substract 6.64 from 100, which gives me 93.36. I divide that in two because I have two columns. So every column width will be 46.68%. */

If you were to add padding, you would need to declare the following:

```
article { box-sizing:border-box; }
```

This will keep your columns from breaking.

CSS Tricks has a great tutorial on how to use flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
section {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:80%;
}
article {
  background: grey;
  width:21.68%;
  margin: 1.66%;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <section> 
        <!-- Project previews -->
        <article>
            <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg" alt="image">
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        
        <article>
            <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg" alt="image">
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview with some content that makes it extend onto another line.</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        
        <article>
            <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg" alt="image">
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        
        <article>
            <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg" alt="image">
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        
        <article>
            <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg" alt="image">
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        
        <article>
            <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/hd_sky_picture_05_hd_pictures_166299.jpg" alt="image">
             <div class="thumb">
               <h3 class="thumb-title">Box One</h3>
               <p class="thumb-description">Item preview</p>
             </div>
        </article>
        
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did want to keep float however. Although I appreciate your response :-)

Answer (score 1):

Overflow has nothing to do with it. Your divs are different in height... In order to display them correctly, set the height of description container.

Comment: A fixed `height` will not extend, or fit the div though will it? If there is too much content within the div, with a height set, it will just cut it off won't it? If you then add an `overflow:auto`, it will give the description a sidebar which is not what I am after...?

Answer (score 0):

you must give the .project-thumbnail static height

```
.project-thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 365px;
}
```

[image]

[image]